# Error 91 while declaring connection string vb6 ADODC

Tags: vb6

What I am doing wrong?

```
Public Function getRecords(query As String) As Adodc
    With Adodc1
        .RecordSource = query
        .Refresh
    End With
    getRecords = Adodc1
End Function
```

Getting an error in line `getRecords = Adodc1` where it shows nothing or Error 91.

The Code is written in a form consisting Adodc1 Control for ADODC object.

Comment: Dim adodc1 As New Adodc
Without the new adodc1 is 'Nothing'

Comment: Shows Invalid use of new keyword @Rob

Comment: Your project does reference adodb and you do have the adodc control available?

Comment: Because it is a control you cannot just do a 'new'. You will need to use a control from a form

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Moved the whole code to a Form,added ADODC control to the form, made required changes, showing nothing to be sent back (Same error 91).

Comment: Can you change your question to reflect the changes?

Comment: Changed the question to reflect changes

Comment: You might need: set getRecords = Adodc1

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother !! It worked like a charm... Thanks a lot

Comment: Seems like a weird solution.  No idea why this is a function at all, since all it does is fiddle with a control and then return a reference to that sited control which already has module level scope anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution by Rob :
set getRecords = Adodc1